# Xperia Z1 camera problem

Tags: camera, bootloader, sony-xperia-z1

I need someone who knows about flashing, bootloader unlocking and related topics for this problem:

My Xperia Z1 doesn't take photos when the app tries to focus. With no focus enabled it goes perfectly.

*Details:*

- I've read that unlocking bootloader in this phone model could make the camera useless, but when I try to see the unlocking status I get this: Rooting Status: Unknown. So I don't know if it's been unlocked or not (I bought it used at eBay).
- I've tried disabling stamina mode and flashing firmware again (5.0.2 and then autoupdated to 5.1.1) but stills the same.

**Questions:**

- Does somebody know the exact solution to my problem?
- If not, could it be related to camera software (I mean, the hardware's internal software, not the app)?
- Could it be related to Android version? Maybe downgrading would solve it?
- At least, how could I know which is my bootloader status?
- Any other help you think that could help